# Having trouble finding where the issue in this logcat message

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

I just can't seem to find the root of the crash in this logcat message. I really hope someone can help with it. If not no worries. Here is the message I'm getting right before the app crashes: (i'm really sorry for it being so long)

> 09-11 11:34:00.889 22547-22547/co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana, PID: 22547
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.User.getTitle()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.fragments.PatientInofrmationFragment.onCreateView(PatientInofrmationFragment.java:76)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3076)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18926)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2411)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1429)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1677)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
>                                                                               at androi

OnCreateView Code:

```
    //----------------find by view--------------
    mTextName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_text_name_patient);
    mEditFirstname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_editText_firstname);
    mEditLastname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_editText_lastname);
    mTextEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_text_email_patient);
    mEditEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_editText_email);
    mTextPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_text_phone_patient);
    mEditPhone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_editText_phone);
    mTextNum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_text_num_patient);
    mEditNum = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_editText_num);
    mTextHCP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_text_hcp_patient);
    mEditHCP = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Patient_info_editText_hcp);

    mEditFirstname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mEditLastname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTextName.setText(PatientActivity.sPatient.getLastname()+" "+PatientActivity.sPatient.getFirstname());
    mEditEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTextEmail.setText(PatientActivity.sPatient.getEmail());
    mEditPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTextPhone.setText(Long.toString(PatientActivity.sPatient.getPhone_number()));
    mEditNum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTextNum.setText(PatientActivity.sPatient.getPatient_number());
    mEditHCP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTextHCP.setText(format("{0}. {1}", PatientActivity.sHCP.getTitle(), PatientActivity.sHCP.getLastname()));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: It's right at the beginning. In `PatientInofrmationFragment.onCreateView` you're calling `getTitle()` at line 76 on some User model but there seem to be no instance of User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your crash look at this line.

```
co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.User.getTitle()' on a null object reference
```

I think you have not **initialized** the **User**.

Check your initialization or if you're receiving it from server make sure to check the **User model** is **Not null**.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to java and android studio, how do I initialize the user?

Comment: Can you post your code where you playing with user model.

Comment: There are a lot of instances of when I use the User model but here is the line 76. `mTextHCP.setText(PatientActivity.sHCP.getTitle()+ ". "+PatientActivity.sHCP.getLastname());`

Comment: is your `sHcp` model is static?

Comment: Yes it is public static

Comment: Ok. your `sHCP` model is null. where u have initialized the `sHCP` variable.

Comment: The variable is set up here `sHCP=MainActivity.sMyHCP;`

Comment: I can't help you without code. anyway, check your initialization of `sHCP` model. before the `mTextHcp.setText` line check `PatientActivity.sHCP != null` you won't get this error. And find where the model turning into null.

Comment: @MwikalaKangwa In your Question add your code for onCreateView so that people can help you

Comment: you may set value to `sHCP` right?. where is that code. post that activity code.

Comment: There is 3 occurrences of the `sHCP`:`public static User sHCP;``sHCP=MainActivity.sMyHCP;``sHCP=hcp_tmp;``mTextHCP.setText(sHCP.getTitle() + ". "+ sHCP.getLastname());`

Comment: check your hcp_tmp is not null

Comment: No I haven't found anything that says `hcp_tmp == null`

Comment: Please check where the sHCP went null. Your error says sHCP is null.

Comment: Okay finally got it sorted found the `sHCP` was null and changed that in the activity. Thank you @BhuvaneshBs

Answer (score 0):

Root of the problem here:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.User.getTitle()' on a ***null object
>   reference*** at
>   co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.fragments.PatientInofrmationFragment.onCreateView(PatientInofrmationFragment.java:76)
>   at

Answer (score 0):

The exception is a NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.User.getTitle()' on a null object reference

You are trying to call the .getTitle() method on a null instance.

The exception has been thrown here:

> co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.fragments.PatientInofrmationFragment.onCreateView(PatientInofrmationFragment.java)

at line 76

Answer (score 0):

Its a `NullPointerException` And you can read it in the first 3 lines -

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.model.User.getTitle()' on a null object reference at co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.fragments.PatientInofrmationFragment.onCreateView(PatientInofrmationFragment.java:76) at

Clearly says **NullPointerException** when you do **User.getTitle()** in your **PatientInofrmationFragment** in its **onCreateView** method.

Now how is it null? You might not have created an object of your **User** class.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like in the PatientInofrmationFragment.onCreateView() the User is null, so User.getTitle() has create a exception. you can init the view in the onCreateView(), and update data in the onActivityCreated().

Comment: if(isAdd() && User != null){ String tilte = User.getTitle();}